# mysql join tables and display fk values

Tags: mysql, join

So, I have a table `spiller` with players and their id.

```
id | navn
-------------
1  | John Doe
2  | Matoma
3  | Lemaitre
4  | Koan
```

Secondly i have a table `spillerpar` that puts players in pairs. This table consist of an Auto inc id and the foreign key of `spiller` id x 2.

```
id | spiller_id_fk_1 | spiller_id_fk_2
--------------------------------------
1  | 1               | 4
2  | 3               | 2
```

Im trying to display the values of 2 fk's along with the fk id. I cant figure out how to. Please help.

```
select a.sid1, a.spiller1, b.sid2, spiller2
FROM
(Select 1_spillerpar.spiller_id_fk_1 as sid1, 1_spiller.navn as spiller1
From 1_spillerpar
Join 1_spiller
ON 1_spillerpar.spiller_id_fk_1 = 1_spiller.id) as a,
(Select 1_spillerpar.spiller_id_fk_2 as sid2, 1_spiller.navn as spiller2
From 1_spillerpar
Join 1_spiller
ON 1_spillerpar.spiller_id_fk_2 = 1_spiller.id) as b
```

**EDIT**

Desired output would look like:

```
id | spiller_id_fk_1 | navn    | spiller_id_fk_2 | navn
--------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1               | John Doe| 4               | Koan
2  | 3               | Lemaitre| 2               | Matoma
```

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: @thebjorn - see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select s1.*,s2.* from spillerpar x
Join spiller s1 on s1.id = spiller_id_fk_1 
Join spiller s2 on s2.id = spiller_id_fk_2
```

Spillerpar.id is redundant

Comment: This works! Allthough I dont fully understand what you did. Would it bother you to explain how it works or point me to somewhere to read? Im thinking of s1 and s2 not being any of my tables.

Comment: s1 is an alias for spiller. So is s2

Answer (score 0):

Strawberry's answer works as expected I think. An alternative is:

```
SELECT sp.id as `pairId`, s1.*,s2.* FROM spillerpar sp, spiller s1, spiller s2
WHERE s1.id = sp.spiller_id_fk_1 AND s2.id = sp.spiller_id_fk_2
```

SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69b1fe/5)

(Edited fiddle to match fk names + added pairId)

Comment: I just don't think we should be promoting this kind of archaic join syntax on SO

Comment: Agreed, my SQL is kinda outdated :(. Any good tutorial would be appreciated!